# To find a maximal ideal in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt m]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ideals

> Suppose $m\in \Bbb{Z}$ is not a square and $m=c^2 \bmod p$ ($p$ prime) for some $c\in \Bbb{Z}$. Prove that $$I_p=\{a+b\sqrt m :p\mid a,\ p\mid b \}$$ is an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt m]$, but **not** a maximal ideal.

My work:

I have shown the ideal part. But I am not being able to find an *ideal* that is bigger than $I_p$.

Suspect: I did not need the fact that $m=c^2 \bmod p$ to show that $I_p$ is an ideal. And $m-c^2$ is divisible by $b$. But I am not getting what the **super**-ideal is.

Comment: You don't have to explicitly find the ideal; it's enough to show that the quotient isn't a field.  (You should probably find the ideal anyway, though.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$I_p=(p)$, the principal ideal generated by $p$ just by definition. But $(p)$ factors in your ring since $m$ is a square modulo $p$.

$(p)=(p,c-\sqrt{m})(p,c+\sqrt{m})$ since $c^2-m=kp$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
In particular, $I_p \subset (p,c-\sqrt{m})$.

To show $(p,c-\sqrt{m})$ is not the whole ring, you can argue directly showing 1 is not a "linear" combination or use the surjective homomorphism:

$\phi: \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$ where $\phi(a+b\sqrt{m})=a+bc$ (mod $p$).

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Is $(p,c-\sqrt m)$ an ideal?

Comment: @Qwerty it's the ideal generated by $p$ and $c-\sqrt{m}$.

Comment: @Charter Is the ideal of this form?$$I=\{a+b\sqrt m\ :\ a,b\in (p,c-\sqrt m)\}$$

Comment: @Qwerty $(p,c-\sqrt{m})= \{up+v(c-\sqrt{m}): u,v\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]\}$.

Comment: Notice $I_p=(p)=\{up : u \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]\}$.

Comment: I don't know why, but I am having some calculations problem in proving that $p,c-\sqrt m)$ is an ideal. Can you please show the multiplication part? I have done the subtraction part(of the proof to be ideal)

Comment: Use the definition Charter gave. If $r \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$, $x \in (p,c-\sqrt{m})$, then $x=up+v(c-\sqrt{m})$ for some $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$. $rx=(ru)p+(rv)(c-\sqrt{m})$ and $ru,rv \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$. So $rx \in (p,c-\sqrt{m})$.

Comment: @ET93 Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

$J$ is a maximal ideal in $R$ iff $R/J$ is a field. Now
$$
\frac{\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt m]}{I_p}
\cong \frac{\Bbb{Z}[X]}{(p,X^2-m)}
\cong \frac{\Bbb{Z}_p[X]}{(X^2-m)}
\cong \frac{\Bbb{Z}_p[X]}{(X-c)} \times \frac{\Bbb{Z}_p[X]}{(X+c)}
$$
is not a field (*). Therefore, $I_p$ is not maximal.

(*) The product of two nontrivial rings is never a field because it has zero divisors: $(1,0) \cdot (0,1) = (0,0)$

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I mean , can you explain the equivalence statements?

Comment: You can define a map like I did from $Z[\sqrt{m}]$ to $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]/(X^2-m)$ by sending $a+b\sqrt{m}$ to $a+bX$. Check that it is a homomoprhism. It is surjective and the kernel is $I_p$.

Comment: @lhf Why don't finish the job ending up with $\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_p$?

Comment: @user26857, because what I wrote is enough to prove that the ideal is not maximal since the product of two nontrivial rings is never a field.

Comment: $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{m}]/I_p$ is not a field since the frobenius automorphism $a+b\sqrt{m} \mapsto (a+b\sqrt{m} )^p \bmod p$ is the identity for $p$ an odd prime and for $p = 2$ it is  not an automorphism